# How to download large file using PHP

Tags: php, webserver, remote-server, large-files, downloading-website-files

I was trying to download 7GB *.tar* file from web link to my web server by using some online available PHP code. However, the file stopped downloading when it reached around 4GB.

My webserver have unlimited storage, so what is causing this problem?

Is there anyway to download such a large file without stopping?

Or any web server software/plug-in for this purpose?

**Thanks**

Comment: Please read this page: [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does the error log show? What file system is the server running? You need to narrow down the issue before we can provide a solution. File system could be an issue, execution time, memory size (if you are storing file into script before writing it), etc.